# Grand total on a SSAS driven pivot table

Tags: excel, ssas

We are using a <del>SASS</del> SSAS driven pilot table where we would like to add a calculated measure using the sum of a column.
We don't know in advance which filters the users will be using, the measure is valid for any of them, so we just tried adding a calc measure on the excel file such as

```
[Measures].[Sales]/sum(axis(1),[Measures].[Sales])
```

But it doesn't seem to work. So just to test we started with a plain

```
sum(axis(1),[Measures].[Sales])
```

which gives some astonishing result.
We cannot figure out what the result is adding up! Applying some filters and a detailed row, we get exactly twice the expected value (!!??).
Applying exactly the same filters and filtering also the rows, we get a value that we are not able to guess where it comes from.

Any idea about what MDX should we use?

Edited to clarify: We want to add the calculated measure on an Excel pivot table, not on the SSAS olap cube definition.

Comment: Please clarify what technologies you're *actually* using.  Sass is a CSS preprocessor.

Comment: oooops! Sorry, my fault. We are using Microsoft SSAS (Sql Server Analysis Services) and not SASS,

Answer (score 0):

I obviously was having a bad day. One cannot think excel-like to solve an mdx issue.

A simple

```
([MyDim].[MyHierarchy].currentmember.parent,[Measures].[Sales])
```

is the right syntax to use in our calculus as the "parent total".

Thks